# Right-continuous process is measurable with respect to product measure.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ be a collection of real random variables such that the map $t\mapsto X_t$ is right-continuous. Show that the map $(t,\omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is measurable with respect to the product measure $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+})\otimes\mathcal{F}$. There a standard argument which I will outline below but I do not understand it all so will hope some one can fill in the gaps for me.

Firstly define for $t\geq0$ and $k\in\{0,1,...,n2^n-1\}$,

$X^{(n)}_t(\omega):=X_{(k+1)/2^n}(\omega)$,  for $\frac{k}{2^n}<t\leq\frac{k+1}{2^n}$.

Now it is claimed that $X_t^{(n)}$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)\otimes\mathcal{F}$-measurable, but I am not sure why? And this  my 1st question.  Now we know that $X_{(k+1)/2^n}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, and that I think we can write $X^{(n)}_t(\omega):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n2_n}1_{\frac{k}{2^n}<t\leq\frac{k+1}{2^n}\}}{X_{(k+1)/2^n}}(\omega)$ but am not sure why this is measurable w.r.t. the product $\sigma$-algebra, so would appreciate if anyone could fill in the gaps.

Secondly I can see that for a fixed $\omega$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X^{(n)}_t=X_t$a.s. in $\Omega$, but then not sure how this implies that the map converges in the product space as $\omega$ won't be fixed or am just confusing matters? And the right continuity comes to play as we have a decreasing sequence, is that correct?  So any help to clear up this matter is greatly needed.

Thirdly I was wondering if using the limiting sequence of $X_{(\lfloor nt\rfloor+1)/n}$ would work better but still have the same measurability questions as before. Also I can see that $(\lfloor nt\rfloor+1)/n\rightarrow t$ but am a bit stuck showing it is a decreasing sequence.

Also for the converse of this result, i.e. every process that is measurable to the product $\sigma$-algebra has a right continuous modification, is it true and where can I find a reference for it? I am also looking for a reference for the result, that any processes that is product measurable and adapted to a filtration on the space has a progressively-measurable modification. 
So any help with any of these queries is greatly needed and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We treat the case of right-continuous and define the sequence of processes
$X_{s}^{(n)}(\omega)$ = \begin{cases}
X_{(k+1)t/2^n}(\omega),&\text{if $kt/2^n <s\leq (k+1)t/2^n$} ,\\
X_0(\omega),&\text{if $s=0$}
\end{cases}
for $t>0, n \geq 1, k = 0,1,\cdots,2^n - 1.$
 For any $B \in \mathcal{B}$, the set

{$(s,\omega)$: $0 \leq s \leq t, \omega \in \Omega, X_{s}^{(n)}(\omega) \in B$} =$\{0\} \times \{\omega: X_0(\omega)\in B\}\bigcup (\bigcup_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} (kt/2^n, (k+1)t/2^n] \times \{\omega:X_{(k+1)t/2^n}(\omega) \in B\}$

is in $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{F}_t$ since X is adapted. Hence $X_s^{(n)}(\omega)$ with $0 \leq s \leq t$ and $\omega \in \Omega$ is $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{F}_t$ measurable for each $n\geq 1$. By that right continuity we have
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_s^{(n)}(\omega) = X_s(\omega)$ for all $0\leq s \leq t, \omega \in \Omega.$ We conclude that $X$ is progressively measurable since limits of measurable function are measurable.